What's the point of D3DCreateBlob function?
If D3DCreateBlob just allocates a piece of host's RAM as a buffer, why not use standard methods (new, malloc etc.) for buffer allocation instead?

Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description which "standard" methods you are referencing to.

The ID3DBlob COM object in the D3DCompiler is an interface so that the various compiler methods have a way to return variable sized memory buffers since DirectX uses the "COM lite" model rather than true COM which has a lot more rules and features to it.
The "real COM" approach would be to use the CoTaskMemAlloc method which would require all callers to APIs that take ID3DBlob to instead have to call CoTaskMemFree.

Technically speaking, the memory used by ID3DBlob comes from the same allocator that the internal Direct3D API methods are using which ultimately uses the OS only "MSVCRT.DLL" instance of the C/C++ Runtime DLL malloc and not the C/C++ Runtime retail DLL your program is built using. Over the long history of Windows these have not always been the same heap, although in practice it's all just layers on top of the Win32 HeapAlloc API using the GetProcessHeap instance these days.

See Programming DirectX with COM.
